# while loop and foreach loop not working as intended mvc application

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I have a table containing a bounch of movies and I want to echo out all of them. But something is wrong with my loops so I'm just getting the first movie.

Here is the code in my moviemodel.

```
public function getMovieList() {
        $test = new DbConnection();
        $dbh = $test->dbcon('localhost', 'root', '6662257', 'mvc');

        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY movie_id");
        $sql->execute();

        while($row = $sql->fetch()){    
            $title = $row['movie_title'];
            $description = $row['movie_des'];
            $link = $row['movie_link'];

        return array(
        $title => new Movie($title, $description, $link) 
        );

        }
    }
```

And here is the code in my movielist:

```
echo '<h1>Movies of 2014</h1>';
    foreach ($movies as $title => $movie) {
        echo '<div class="content"><a href="index.php?movie='.$movie->title.'">'.$movie->title.'</a><br/>'.$movie->description.'</div>';
    }
```

And it still just echo'es out the first movie in my db. I'm new in MVC so I can't figure out where the problem lies. I appriciate help of any kind.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `return` in your loop. This will lead to the end of the function, and so return just the first movie from your query.

Extract into something like that, and you will be good to go.

```
public function getMovieList() {
    $test = new DbConnection();
    $dbh = $test->dbcon('localhost', 'root', '6662257', 'mvc');

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY movie_id");
    $sql->execute();

    $movies = array();

    while($row = $sql->fetch()){    
        $title = $row['movie_title'];
        $description = $row['movie_des'];
        $link = $row['movie_link'];
        $movies[$title] = new Movie($title, $description, $link);
    }

    return $movies;
}
```

Comment: To add some context to why this works. You can only return from a function once. Hence, you need to build an array of all the movie objects, and return that.

Comment: I see, had no idea hehe. This worked out absolutely perfect, thank you very much, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can! @ThomasRuiz

Answer (score 2):

you return just from the first iteration of the while loop, consider filling an array and return that:

```
    $movies = array();
    while($row = $sql->fetch()){    
        $title = $row['movie_title'];
        $description = $row['movie_des'];
        $link = $row['movie_link'];

        $movies[] = new Movie($title, $description, $link);
    }
    return $movies;
```

Comment: $movies is array, not object :) You have to return $movies without `()`

Answer (score 1):

You got to be new in functions, not in MVC :)

Functions has only one return value.

```
for ($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    return $i;
}
```

will return on first iteration and the function will stop.

You need to return the array and use loop to iterate over the function

```
while (condition) {
    $movie[$title] = new Movie($title, $description, $link)
}
return $movie;
```